Is it possible to make a constant DAC controlled current source using LT3092
I am trying to make a constant current source using LT3092 .My DAC maximum output is 3.3V and at that time the current source needs to generate a current of 20mA.
For generating 20mA the RSET(R1 in schematic) value needs to be 165 Ohm . Please see my circuit below.

The issue what I am facing is my load will come in series with RSET and this is changing the
desired current.
May I know is there any way to solve this issue.
Below is the circuit with load.You can see that the current is changed.


bit confused, why use that chip if you want to use it as a voltage-to-current converter with fixed offset voltage? Wouldn't a resistor connected to your DAC output do exactly the same?

Yes, you should be able to do this here is an example with a LT3083, which has a similar block diagram:

One problem with these setups is the current offset of the positive terminal, so if you need this to be linear at lower current's a better setup would be to use a current sense resistor with feedback with your own opamp and transistor.
Make sure you also have a sufficient buffer between the DAC and LT3092, any loading can reduce the accuracy of DAC's.
I'd probably go with a circuit like this if you don't need the lowest noise performance, you can calibrate it with an ADC and calibrate the currents if you have a known resistor:

Source: Precision 1nA - 10mA current source

May I know how this Lt3083 act as a constant current source
